# Add to cart in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to do the add to cart function on an image which is a link to cart page. I have written the following code

simple.php

```
<form class="cart" method="post" onSubmit="return validateIn('<?= $product->id?>');" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button' ); ?>

    <?php
        if ( ! $product->is_sold_individually() )
            woocommerce_quantity_input( array(
                'min_value' => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_min', 1, $product ),
                'max_value' => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_max', $product->backorders_allowed() ? '' : $product->get_stock_quantity(), $product )
            ) );
    ?>
```

I have done an animation on add to cart after which I am trying to add the code for add to cart

```
function validateIn(p_id){

//code for animation
event.preventDefault();
    addToCart(p_id);
  return false;




}
function addToCart(p_id) {
        jQuery.ajax({
          type: 'POST',

          url: 'addtocart.php',

          data: { 'product_id':  p_id,
          },
          success: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR){


            console.log("Product added");
            }
        }); 
  }
```

Can anybody tell me how to proceed!!Pls Help

Answer (score 2):

In the php page ajax url page,

`global $woocommerce;
$woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart($product_id);`

Comment: did you you tried to get the post data.i mean product id in the url page?

Comment: yes $product_id=$_POST['product_id'];global $woocommerce;
$woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart($product_id); this is my code now.

Comment: try to dump post data,to check if data is passing correctly

Comment: 75 is the product id which is getting passed

Comment: yes..im getting post data..am i missing some referencing files??

Comment: did you include config.php.If no pls do that

Comment: sorry I did not get you..which config file?

Comment: wp-config file in the root folder

Comment: <?php wp_head(); ?> is dr in my header.php.. Does this take care of includingwp-config?